# How to solve 'Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold' content for multiple files?

Tags: css, javascript, optimization

I get this when I check my site in google insight:

[image: google insight]

Pretty ok right? But I still consider to fix **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content** to get a good results on mobiles too.

I am adding CSS, JS files using the code below:

```
/* loading the default styles of the theme */
function theme_style_sheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800', '', '1.0.0'  );   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css', '', '1.0.0'  );   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', '', '1.0.0'  );   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-responsive.css', '', '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'camera', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/camera.css', '', '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'docs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/docs.css', '', '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prettyphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/prettyPhoto.css', '', '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css', '', '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tango-skin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/skins/tango/skin.css', '', '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_style_sheets' );

/**
 * loading the default scripts of the theme
 */
function theme_scripts() {      
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquer-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquer-mobile', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'camera', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/camera.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquer-prettyphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquer-jcarousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.jcarousel.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquer-tweet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.tweet.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );

function load_external_jQuery() { // load external file  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"), false);   
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');    
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_external_jQuery');
```

So as per the above code the JS files should be loaded in footer and those are loading into the footer.
BUT still google includes those files in **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content** why ??

Also I've tried differ method like : http://moz.com/community/q/fixing-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-the-above-the-fold-content
But the out put remains same.

Also in that method I have to combine all the JS / CSS files.
I do not want to combine all files into one.

I tried some other snippets too for differing multiple files. Also the out put is same.

Now google insight shows this:

[image: Google insight 2]

How can I solve this WITHOUT using any plugin.????

There are plenty of plugins to do this. But I do not use any plugin in my current site and I like to keep avoiding plugins.

Answer (score -1):

put this code at the end of functions.php

```
add_action('customize_register', 'customizer');
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return "$url' defer ";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```